# @media не меняет ширину и высоту

Tags: html, css

```
 #bord{
  width: 100%;
 }

 @media screen and (max-device-width: 654px) {
 #bord{
    width: 50%;
 }
}
```

Не могу поменять ширину блока медиа запросом.
Сам медиа запрос вроде работает, к примеру меняет background-color
а ширину менять не хочет.

Comment: а где высота-то у вас?

Comment: попробуйте @media screen and (max-width: 654px)

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 654px) уже пробовал

Comment: Почему думаете, что запрос работает, а ширину не меняет? Как проверяли?

Comment: google chrome, developer tools

Comment: тег meta viewport в head присутствует?

Comment: да, присутствует

Comment: вариант с @media screen and (max-width: 654px) - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/p5zgfwr2/  Более подробно - https://habrahabr.ru/company/paysto/blog/254871/

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было указать селектор родительского элемента

Вот так:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 654px) {
.wrapper #bord{
   width: 50%;
 }
}
```

Comment: А ещё надо приучиться не использовать в стилях идентификаторы